# Laravel Eloquent: adding variable inside where like clause (undefined variable)

Tags: sql, laravel, variables, eloquent, sql-like

```php
$search_category = "Gen";
$all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::query()
    ->when(empty($search_category), function ($query) {
        $query->where('category_id', '>=', '1');
    })
    ->when(!empty($search_category), function ($query) {
        $query->where('category_name', 'LIKE', "%$search_category%");
    })
    ->orderBy('category_id', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

my `!empty()` will trigger since `$search_category` has a value. I also need the same value of `$search_category` to be used inside the `LIKE %%`.

adding `'LIKE', "%$search_category%"` gives me `"message": "Undefined variable: search_category",`

How do I fix the undefined variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of variable's scope. Your variable not exists in callback scope. Use `use` keyword to pass it there like this:

```php
->when(!empty($search_category), function ($query) use ($search_category) {
    $query->where('category_name', 'LIKE', "%$search_category%");
});
```